# how to write this for loop in a better way in typescript without using loop

Tags: typescript

I wanna find out a proper way to write this for loop.

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'labelvaluepairs' })
export class LabelValuePairsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args: string[]): any {
        let dropdownArr = [];
        dropdownArr.push({ 'label': 'All', 'value': null });

        for (let key in value) {
            dropdownArr.push({ 'label': value[key], 'value': key });
        }
        return dropdownArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's not working? If all you are concerned about is the style, this is not a code review website, there are actual code review communities on stackexchange. We can help you if something is not working properly and needs fixing.

Comment: Is there any issue with your code? If there isn't, this question might be more suitable for Code Review SE.

Comment: I want to write it without using loop.